# Adding http link inside displayed text - PHP (WooCommerce Email)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hyperlink, woocommerce

Im trying to add a link inside some PHP text that displays in an email sent out by woo commerce. I'd like to add a link through to my website so that where it says XXXXX below, it says 'here.' but I must be doing something wrong as the code crashes and can't be read properly with all the various things I'm trying such as print and echo.

```
<p><?php _e( "Your order has been received and is now being processed. We will send you another email shortly to let you know that your order has been shipped. If you'd like to track the status of your order, you can by clicking XXXXXXX. Your order details are shown below for your reference:", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried not using an `echo` to print that string? I.e. placing that string directly on the HTML: `<p>Your order ... by clicking <a href="http://your.domain">XXXXX</a>. Your order...</p>`.

Comment: If you really need to use [`_e` in Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) to translate the string according to the domain provided in the second parameter, try to understand if the crash is related to the `$domain` (in your case `woocommerce`). This question may be useful if you describe exactly what you are trying in order to place that link and if there is any error when the "code crashes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this you can divide you string in two parts like below

```
<p><?php _e( "Your order has been received and is now being processed. We will send you another email shortly to let you know that your order has been shipped. If you'd like to track the status of your order, you can by clicking ", 'woocommerce' ); ?><a href="http://example.com" title="">XXXXXXX</a><?php _e( "Your order details are shown below for your reference:", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
```